# Rearranging XML in the most efficient way

Tags: java, xml

I have an input data that is structured like this:

```
<Camera ID = 1></Camera>
<Camera ID = 2></Camera>
<Camera ID = 3></Camera>
<Manufacturer ID = 1>A</Manufacturer>
<Manufacturer ID = 2>B</Manufacturer>
<Manufacturer ID = 3>C</Manufacturer>
<Size ID = 1>360</Size>
<Size ID = 2>240</Size>
<Size ID = 3>380</Size>
```

But I want to arrange it like this:

```
<Camera ID = 1><Manufacturer>A</Manufacturer><Size>360</Size></Camera>
<Camera ID = 2><Manufacturer>B</Manufacturer><Size>240</Size></Camera>
<Camera ID = 3><Manufacturer>C</Manufacturer><Size>380</Size></Camera>
```

I'm forced to do this because the program which returns the value runs asynchronously, i.e. the first function returns all the names, then the second one returns the list of manufacturers etc. The function generating the output is in C and I'm reading it using Java.

Comment: The tags c and java are not relevant.

Comment: @moffeltje IMHO, `java` should be there, not `C`.

Comment: Are the three returned lists guaranteed to be always the same size and in correct order?

Comment: Will every `Manufacturer` node will have its ID set to the camera that it manufactured? So there may be multiple `Manufacturer`-nodes that describe the same manufacturer, but with different `ID`s?

Comment: Yes, multiple Manufacturer node will all have unique IDs, but the value may be the same. I.e. two different cameras with same Manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do that, depending if you want to parse the Xml yourself or not.

You can use a `Sax` (or `StAx`) parser and 3 Maps to store the `Camera`, the `Manufacturer` and the `Size` by their `ID`. I am thinking of solution like this :

```
String cameraXml = getAllCameras();
List<Integer> camerasByIds = parseCamera(cameraXml, new CameraSaxHandler());

String manufacturerXml = getAllManufacturers();
Map<Integer, String> manufacturerById = parse(manufacturerXml, new ManufacturerSaxHandler());

String sizeXml = getAllSizes();
Map<Integer, Integer> sizesById = parse(sizeXml, new SizeSaxHandler());
```

I will let you figure out how to write the `parse` method.

Once you have done, you can easily generate a the Xml following your structure.